# Paypal: email a payment link & callback

Tags: php, paypal

Using Paypal, what is the easiest way to create a page on which a user can pay a specific amount determined by me?

Basically, a request for a service is displayed in a custom CMS and the system calculates the price automatically. The admin reviews the price and then clicks a button to send a link to the requester via which they make the payment.

There is no shopping cart, no shipping details, no quantities, the "look" of the payment page is not important. After the payment is done I'd like to receive a callback to notify me of the payment.

What's the best way to go about this?

EDIT: I ended up using [Ran Arrousi's Paypal lib for CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib) to build a form that can be submitted to paypal and then the same library to integrate PayPal IPN which checks if the payment was received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the 'Buy now' Buttons [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside).

With this you can easily create speficic buttons that can be included in your website by simply adding a html snippet. to change the payment amount you can change the hidden field of the generated html specifying the amount.

By default you get notifications via email. If you want the Instant Payment Notifications of Paypal you can get all the informations about it [here](https://www.paypal.com/ipn).

Note that you will have to have a handler for the ipns on your webserver that not only handles the notifications but also verifies them by sending them back to paypal (all described under the link).